# Early 2000s sf game with kangaroo-like enemies

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Late 1990s or early 2000s (not later than 2005) PC game (could be console as well, I played on PC).

Set in a Sci-fi setting. Shooter. If I remember correctly 1st person.

I only remember what I think could be a starting area:

Outdoors.

The whole thing is on a floating platform/island, if you go over the edge you die. Near the edge a vehicle/ship is parked, yellow colour (could be wrong on the colour, but I'm pretty sure it was yellow).

In this starting area there are some enemies, they look like kangaroos - they also jump. I think you have a sling that you can use with stones to kill them.

Only other detail I remember was during one of the mission, there is this big ugly monster, and you need to collect some blue/green crystals to charge your weapon or something.

Comment: *[Alien X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvIOhe8V4Zg)* was mentioned in a Reddit thread as having kangaroo-like aliens, but I don't see them in the longplay.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827) to more features of the site. As an unregistered user, you can’t vote, and you’ll lose access to your account if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Once you lose access, you won’t be able to accept answers or edit posts (without requiring other users’ approval) that you made under the unregistered account. Registering an account is easy, and it will allow you to participate more fully in our community.